# IdbConnection vs SqlConnection

Tags: c#, ado.net

Что лучше для работы с базой данных IdbConnection или SqlConnection,я так и не понял,одни люди мне говорят что SqlConnection лучше а IdbConnection лучше не использовать,а другие говорят обратное!

Comment: Если бы сразу поставили правильно метки, получили бы ответ раньше. Будьте внимательнее в следующий раз.

Answer (score 1):

- `IDbConnection` и сопутствующие - это наиболее общие интерфейсы ADO.NET.
- `SqlConnection` и сопутствующие - это классы, разработанные специально для работы с MS SQL Server.

В любом случае, вам потребуются специализированные классы ADO-коннектора для конкретной базы данных, т.к. именно в них определены правила и логика взаимодействия с конкретной БД. Использование общих интерфейсов позволит, в теории, сконцентрировать работу со специализированными классами в каком-нибудь DbManager вашего приложения, а все остальные действия выполнять независимо от конкретной БД лежащей под этим менеджером.

Если собираетесь работать исключительно с MS SQL, то можете использовать специализированные классы непосредственно. Разумеется, это доставит вам проблемы если соберетесь, внезапно, изменить БД на Oracle, PostgreSQL или что-то другое.

Общие интерфейсы ADO, могут помочь вашему приложению работать с любой БД, если для нее существует ADO.NET-коннектор, но тут есть нюансы с сопоставлением типов данных между родными типами .NET (CLR), типами [DbType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.dbtype(v=vs.110).aspx) и родными типами БД, определенными в перечислении ADO-коннектора (например [SqlDbType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqldbtype(v=vs.110).aspx)), которое может доставить некоторое количество сюрпризов. Впрочем, это отдельный вопрос.